# WebVR Gamepad Extensions won't enable on Samsung S8

Tags: samsung-mobile, webvr, gamepad, gear-vr

I have a Samsung S8 with a GearVR headset. WebVR is working fine in both Oculus and Samsung Internet browser, but the Gamepad Extensions won't enable.

I have toggled both WebVR and Gamepad Extensions flags using internet://flags

The controller is working fine in non-WebVR apps. But any webpage that uses WebVR does not have a functioning controller (e.g. https://threejs.org/examples/webvr_gearvr.html) . No gamepads are found in the array returned by navigator.getGamepads()

Any thoughts on what the issue could be, or how to debug further?

Comment: I am guessing you are using Three.js. Have you tried using https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/vr/GearVRController.js ?

Comment: Yeah I am using those examples to test this issue.  Though I can also repro in trivial Javascript snippet that just dumps the contents of the gamepad array from the navigator.

Comment: May be if you can share some code I might be able to help more. I remember getting the GearVR controller working by using GearVRController.js from Three.js.